# Running Local Version of Schema.org

Tags: google-app-engine, schema.org

I am attempting to run a local version of the schema.org app so I can write a proposal for an addition to the ontology. I followed the tutorial at http://dataliberate.com/2016/02/10/evolving-schema-org-in-practice-pt1-the-bits-and-pieces/, which had me set up Google App Engine and download a forked version of schema.org using Git.

Unfortunately, I cannot get the schema.org app to run on my machine. Sample GAE apps work fine, but whenever I start the schema.org app I get the following error:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Ontology\schemaorg\lib\rdflib\plugins\parsers\pyRdfa\__init__.py", line 580, in graph_from_source
        if not rdfOutput : raise f
rdflib.plugins.parsers.pyRdfa.FailedSource

ERROR2016-09-29 14:54:39,825 wsgi.py:263] 

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 240, in Handle
        handler = _config_handle.add_wsgi_middleware(self._LoadHandler())
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 299, in _LoadHandler
        handler, path, err = LoadObject(self._handler)
File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\runtime\wsgi.py", line 85, in LoadObject
        obj = __import__(path[0])
File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Ontology\schemaorg\sdoapp.py", line 2585, in <module>
        read_schemas(loadExtensions=ENABLE_HOSTED_EXTENSIONS)
File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Ontology\schemaorg\api.py", line 1055, in read_schemas
        apirdflib.load_graph('core',file_paths)
File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Ontology\schemaorg\apirdflib.py", line 118, in load_graph
        g.parse(file=open(full_path(f),"r"),format=format)
File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Ontology\schemaorg\lib\rdflib\graph.py", line 1037, in parse
        parser.parse(source, self, **args)
        File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Ontology\schemaorg\lib\rdflib\plugins\parsers\structureddata.py", line 145, in parse
        check_lite=check_lite
        File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Ontology\schemaorg\lib\rdflib\plugins\parsers\structureddata.py", line 176, in _process
        processor.graph_from_source(orig_source, graph=graph, pgraph=processor_graph, rdfOutput=False)
        File "C:\Users\Kevin\Desktop\Ontology\schemaorg\lib\rdflib\plugins\parsers\pyRdfa\__init__.py", line 662, in graph_from_source
        if not rdfOutput : raise b
FailedSource

INFO 2016-09-29 10:54:39,951 module.py:788] default: "GET /_ah/warmup HTTP/1.1" 500-
```

The problem is occurring when it tries to parse the RDF, but I suspect the lack of RDF output is being caused by the 500 error. I have done an extensive search and found plenty of examples of the 500 error with GAE, but none of the suggested fixes has worked (e.g., increasing the TIMEOUT setting, rolling back to SDK 1.36).

I am running the app on localhost:9080. I get a 500 error whenever I try to access it from the browser. I can, however, access the admin at localhost:8001. For some reason, it shows two instances running.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: You might want to look at my Schema Generator [here](https://github.com/GUI-Junkie/Schema.org-Generator)

Comment: You can see it running [here](http://schema.pythonanywhere.com/)

Answer (score 0):

This problem has now been fixed with a Windows specific patch to the Schema.org code line as referenced in Git Issues ([#1384](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1384)) and ([#1412](https://github.com/schemaorg/schemaorg/issues/1412))

A pull of the latest code from the repository should clear the problem.